# How to start analyze the mail from the oldest one

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office-automation

I've got a macro in Excel that analyze all the mail in outlook and write some parameter in an Excel sheet, it starts from the latest one. How can I start instead from the oldest?

---

I tried the following, which I saw here, but it does not loop throu all the mail in inbox.

```
 Sub SortByDate()
  Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
  Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
  Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim myItems As Outlook.Items

  Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  Set myItems = myFolder.Items
  myItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
  For Each myItem In myItems
   MsgBox myItem.Subject & " ---- " & myItem.ReceivedTime
  Next myItem
 End Sub
```

Comment: The code you have is for Outlook VBA where `Application` is Outlook. In Excel VBA `Application` is Excel. In Excel VBA one possibility is `Dim OutApp as Outlook.Application`, `Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application` and `Set myNamespace = OutApp.GetNamespace…`.

Comment: I replaced Application with Outlook.GetNamespace, the code didn't get all the mail in inbox....it seem it get only the new mail in inbox but not the one that I archived in other folder and put them back in Inbox to test some address...maybe it is a bug of Outlook, maybe someone had the same issue and can help.

Comment: This is likely due to the older items being on the server. There are similar questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595941/programmatically-accessing-archived-mails-in-an-exchange-folder. I cannot apply this advice on my machine, but you may have better luck.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59546486/1571407

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the Inbox folder (assuming that is what you want) using `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)`. Retrieve the `Items` collection from the `MAPIFolder.Items` property, sort the collection by calling `Items.Sort("ReceivedTime", true)`, then loop through the items using `for each`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to [sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.sort) the items in the required order:

```
Items.Sort("ReceivedTime", true)
```

Note that iterating over all items in Outlook is not really a good idea. You may consider using the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class instead. So, you could iterate over items that correspond to your conditions. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Also you may find the `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class helpful. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information.